# multidimensional array value as implode value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, implode

I am facing some problem to fix this issue. My array same as below

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [coupon] => dasd ) [1] => Array ( [coupon] => aaa ) )
```

From here I want to display only **coupon** value as comma separated. Same as below

```
dasd,aaa
```

To solve this I tried below code but that's not solving my issue.

```
<?php
$option_settings = array(
array(  'coupon'=>'dasd'     
    ),
array(  'coupon'=>'aaa')
);
print_r($option_settings );
echo $output = implode(',', $option_settings);
?>
```

Sample https://eval.in/784206

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
    <?php
$option_settings = array(
array(  'coupon'=>'dasd'     
    ),
array(  'coupon'=>'aaa')
);


$arr = array();
foreach($option_settings as $opt) {
  $arr[] = $opt['coupon'];
}
echo $output = implode(',', $arr);
?>
```

Or You can use php function `array_column()`

```
$coupans_arr =array_column($option_settings, 'coupon');
echo $output = implode(",", $coupans_arr);
```

[Live Demo](https://eval.in/784216)

Comment: Don't copy answer from other pls

Comment: @B.Desai I don't think so I copied and `array_column` is php function. And am give two options which one is easy user can use it.

Comment: @B.Desai If I copy the answer form other then I am not give solved link also

Comment: @sandipkakade Thanks for your answer first one helped me. but second one not worked.Can you suggest me why? I am using wordpress.

Comment: @LemonKazi That's because array_column only works on 2-dimensional arrays.

Comment: how about my array the first one I printed ?

Comment: @sandipkakade I accepted your answer. If you feel other person can face this problem in SO u can give a vote on question.

Answer (score 1):

use simple `array_column` method

```
 $option_settings = array(
array(  'coupon'=>'dasd'     
    ),
array(  'coupon'=>'aaa')
);
print_r($option_settings );
$coupans_arr =array_column($option_settings, 'coupon');
echo $output = implode(",", $coupans_arr);
```

https://eval.in/784217

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer . I tried your solution but it was displaying error in my wordpress system array_column undefined function.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want,

```
print_r(implode(',', array_column($array, 'coupon')));
```

Answer (score -1):

Please let me know if this works:

```
$option_settings = array(
array(  'coupon'=>'dasd'     
    ),
array(  'coupon'=>'aaa')
);

$result = '';


foreach($option_settings as $item)
{
    $result .= $item['coupon'] .', ';
}

$result = rtrim($result, ', ');
```

https://eval.in/784220